# Can anyone help me rig a watch escapement?

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have this modeled already but I have no idea how I can properly rig for animation.

[image]

I am specifically looking rig and animate the flat spring underneath. I would love to figure out how to simulate but maybe that is a longshot. Thanks!

Comment: Did you model the spring already? I think concentric rings would be easier to rig...Oh! you can just rotate and shrink the spring while using proportional editing!

Comment: Check on this [spool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137564/30849) answer. Same concept applies here.

Answer (score 4):

**Using bones and curve modifiers**

[image]

The first bone has 100% influence on the spring.

The second one, its child and which is rotating, has a gradient influence on it.

To make this gradient, start with a simple plane and set the weight to 1 for a side (interior side), and to 0 for the second side (exterior side).

[image]

Once done, stretch it and loop cut it.

Now use a spiral curve (add curve extra object standard addon). And add a curve modifier on the spring.

You will need to weight paint a bit on the exterior part that may not move at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I'm still trying to get my head round the interaction of the Z rotation and the Curve modifier.

Comment: The base bone (which does not rotate) as two influences: rotation and positions. That's what is giving the scale effect (at least I think : ).

Comment: Man...that's another amazing answer from you!!!

Comment: seeing what you did, I appreciate the comment all the more. Thanks @Chris.

Comment: Thank you very much lemon‼️‼️I really appreciate that!