# Springy spiral - how to?

Tags: soft-body

I am trying to get a springy spiral which is pinned at the center, think of a metal spiral with 10 revs you would have ie inside a watch. In 3ds max i would just add a Flex modifier, but in Blender i understand i am supposed to use soft body physics.

I did that, yet the spiral never behaves anything metalish, i cannot seem to find settings anywhere close. Animating the spiral with the pinned center always has the effect of a spaghetti or rubber thread being pulled away, i never get the effect of the whole thing following in a wobbly spring fashion.

Any small pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the animation made in 3ds max whit the flex modifier? it would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148794/can-anyone-help-me-rig-a-watch-escapement

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page.

Comment: Now i found an example to clarify my messy description: I am looking how to rig/simulate a so called "hairspring", see example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7r-lxpSv2M
That is basically a flexy metal spiral which is pinned at the axle, and will wobble if moved around or rotated. Couldn't get it right yet and am thankful for any pointer how to apply that on a spiral (Extra Objects Curves) in Blender.

Comment: I got it working: solution for me was a weight proximity (vertex) modifier.