# How to animate a spinning Coil Spring (mechanic watch)

Tags: animation, modifiers, transforms

In a mechanic watch you will find such a coil spring.
The spring is fixed in two points (green crosses) and has a spinning attractor at the inside of the spiral which is moving first clockwise and then after clockwise.
The effect is a "breathing" coilspring. Its compressing and decrompressing from insideout.

I already tried to solve the issue with the "AnimAll" plugin to animate the edit points, but I'm not able to handle the move...

If someone want to try, I can send the hairspring

[Balance Wheel Hairspring Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtO9jAFj6os)

[image: Coil Spring]

Comment: Should be doable with an armature and converting the spring to a mesh.

Comment: This might assist - I just did a Blender search for "Watch". - 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148794/can-anyone-help-me-rig-a-watch-escapement

Comment: Here's another resource that might help - https://youtu.be/HasNkycRZ4c?&t=768