Trying to create realistic balance spring/coil spring animation
I am trying to recreate this but it's nearly impossible because the size of the spring i am working with is with scale to the real size and the solution here leaves out the node group for "segments"
This is what I want:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXkcrHDQPrs
How to animate a Balance Spring with Geonodes
I have the spring already modeled. See:


the same, but with GN? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148868/19156

@lemon I tried this but this is not working. The weights are applied to the child bone yet it doesn't have an effect.  The gradient influence is not working as intended. Also the animation is wrong as explained by the user in the Geo-nodes question. But this is a good solution too if it works with mine.

you mean you already modeled the spring but failed to set the bone weights? Could you updload your model? https://blend-exchange.com/... and, why don't you use the answer in the gn question?

@lemon I have set up the bone weight but the spring doesn't coil with the weight. I will upload the file soon

@lemon https://blend-exchange.com/b/k2rbGYz0/

something was wrong in your armature. recreating it make it work. also getting ride of scales rotations and relative transforms is better. https://blend-exchange.com/b/96Zzn1EY/

there is another point: very small models sometimes have accuracy issues in blender (floating points approximation)

@lemon can you tell what was wrong? I still don't know. It seems like your child bone is bigger in size? This is me first time working with bones so have no clue.

the size is different because I've recreated it. Something was wrong in the bones as the most external parts should not move at all. Though, I was not able to find why your armature is wrong. It is nearly like if the bone influences was inverted

@lemon Can you describe the steps? I again added an armature and it's still working like that. I added the bone, extruded it in edit mode. Got back to object mode, selected the spring, then the bone, then pose mode, and added parent to the bone.

well... once the node group created (Bone with full influence and Bone.001 with gradient influence), simply parent the spring to the armature, using "with empty groups" and all is ok (at least for me here).

This is not physically accurate but it's simple and can be wanted desired effect.


From a curve spiral, on one part, trim the begining of the curve, and in the second part scale it proportionally to its factor.
Trimming the curve: a factor limited between 0 to 0.2 (arbitrary tuned values) plus a minimum.
Scalling the curve: the same factor (also limited to arbitrary values) and used with an exponent so that the scale lowers from 1 at the end of the curve, to the calculated value at its begining.
The input value is then animated and the animation is made cyclic.

The last part of the node tree is to give thickness to the spiral.
 Blender 4.3.2

This works but as you have mentioned is notaccurate. It feels more like the spring is breathing. Can we implement the node group of the other answer with this and get the sam effect?
