# Technical animation, folding sheet while moving it along a vertical path

Tags: animation

I have this idea to make quiet a difficult (technical) animation, where I have some sort of sheet that moves vertically along a path and gets folded along the way.

1: Sheet goes down 
2: Gets pushed between the 2 circles (fold 1)
3: Goes down on the other side
4: Gets pushed between other 2 circles (fold 2)

I've tried a lot of things already, but can't figure out how to do it.

Any ideas/suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site. Some questions: is it for a one way folding animation? Is the folding path constant or should it be variable, for instance adding more tubes (circles) or could the sheet be pushed between circles or not, depending on something? Is the size of the sheet finished or any length?

Comment: Maybe using follow curve modifier for multiple times could help

Comment: as Mohammadreza says, the Curve modifier seems the right way to do it, the curve shape will make the paper sheet fold the way you want

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137564/30849)?

Comment: Yes, I think that curve modifier is the way to go. The problem is the folding. I think that I would try to do that with multiple of stages of shape keys on the curve. It would probably also make sense to switch between multiple curve modifier to break the problem apart into smaller chunks.

Comment: It would also be possible to control the curve via hooks that you could freely animate.