# Animate a UV unwrapped plane bending

Tags: animation

I want to take a flat plane and animate one end of it rolling up to a roughly 90 degree angle.

The plane is UV unwrapped with a repeating texture and needs the distortion to be minimal.

This image roughly shows the before and after of what I'm wanting to accomplish.
[image]

blend file: [image]

Initially, I tried using the curve modifier with a shape key on the curve but I was having issue with the plane sliding around.

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide to clarify.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137554/how-to-create-reeling-spool-effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your curve a bit in *Edit* mode so that its 2 ends go a bit further and instead of creating shapekeys, just move your curve on the Y axis:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Your method is what I tried to do initially but I was missing the extra length on the end of the curve so I was getting some unexpected results.