# Curling a corner on a rolled up object (Not the same as rolling an object or curling a flat plane)

Tags: modeling, curve-modifier

I'm trying to model an object and have it look similar to these example pictures. It will not be animated, just a static image from one angle.

Basically, I want to make a cylindrical object that *appears* to be rolled up where the material on the front is peeling back on the top corner.

My finished model would look most similar to the black image. Camera angle, peel location and amount would be very similar.

It will be a single image so no need to worry about modeling the top or back. I was originally thinking it would make sense to have the main body of the object be a cylinder and then create a curved plane that would be modified to give the illusion that the object is unrolling slightly.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I always struggle a bit trying to get the curve modifier to cooperate and it's a bit more of a complex shape than bending a simple flat plane.

Please let me know if there's any more information I could provide.

Example images of what I'm going for:

[image]
[image]

I previously asked this question and it was closed and marked as a duplicate. The questions that were linked were not doing the same thing I'm trying to accomplish:

- [I'm not curling a flat plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54114/how-to-make-peeling-edges-of-a-paper/)
- [I only want to curl one corner and on a much more complex shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50396/how-can-i-animate-a-mesh-moving-in-a-spiral-fashion)
- [I'm not using animation nodes or animating this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136600/spiral-unrolling-rolling-animation-in-animation-nodes)
- [This isn't curling the corner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137554/how-to-create-reeling-spool-effect/137564#137564)

Answer (score 2):

1. Duplicate some part of cylinder.
2. Scale up in XY plane a bit and separate them.
3. Add a bone or more to deform that part but one bone seem work fine for me.
4. Adjust your bone.
5. Edit Weight Paint.
   [image]
   *Weight Paint (left). After apply Solidify and add material (right).*

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. Now I just need to figure out how to weight paint correctly, I haven't done any rigging previously.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a cloth simulation:

[image]

Create a cylinder, give it a vertex group, give it a *Physics > Cloth*, choose the vertex group as *Pin Group*, enable *Self Collision*. You can pull a vertex with the *Proportional Editing* on in order to bend it a bit already :

[image]

Create a cylinder that will be the roll, give it a *Physics> Collision*:

[image]

Before launching the player, in the *Scene panel > Gravity*, increase the X or Y value up to 5 for example so that it pulls the fabric a bit in the X or Y axis, as well as Z.