How can I bend this rectangle to turn it into a parchment?
Can someone please help me to make these parchment paper, scroll-type menu buttons? I am using 4.2.3. I started transforming scaling a simple mesh cube to be the shape of a piece of parchment paper. See this example that I'm going for, and the viewport screenshot below:
 
I added geometry to the rectangle with Loop Cuts:

And now I have added a "Simple Deform" modifier, set to bend along the "X" axis.

It's hard to describe what the modifier is doing to my geometry, and it's also hard to capture it in a screenshot, but rest assured, I have experimented with bending along multiple axes, with multiple settings, with my rectangle rotated in different ways, and with different faces selected. I want to bend the parchment procedurally, non-destructively. So far all I can get is something like this:

Can anyone please help me to bend the rectangle so it's like a scroll? I have surely used the search function and tried other solutions, such as the one here:
How to bend a plane? Bend won't bend

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136600/spiral-unrolling-rolling-animation-in-animation-nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137554/how-to-create-reeling-spool-effect

You could do it with the Curve modifier: Create a spiral curve (you need to enable the Add Curve: Extra Objects addon then ShiftA > Curve > Curve Spirals > Archemedian) and extrude its tip. Put your object at the same location as the curve:

Give your object a Curve modifier with the curve as Curve Object, move it on X until it rolls around the spiral:

